# How does one animate a 2d grid using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to code langton's ant in python and while the code does work when i test it as an ASCII "simulation" i'm having problems making it work in matplotlib as a 2d animation. I've never really messes with matplotlib but i was trying to learn by doing this.

```
import datetime,pprint,keyboard,time,os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

antLocation = (15,15) # (y,x)
antDirection = 270
grid = [[0 for i in range(30)].copy() for _ in range(30)]

def update(data):
    global grid
    global antLocation
    global antDirection
    if(grid[antLocation[0]][antLocation[1]] == 0):
        antDirection +=90
        grid[antLocation[0]][antLocation[1]] = 1
    else:
        antDirection -=90
        grid[antLocation[0]][antLocation[1]] = 0
    if (antDirection == 0 or antDirection == 360): #UP
        antLocation = (antLocation[0]-1, antLocation[1])
        antDirection = 0
    elif (antDirection == 90): #RIGHT
        antLocation = (antLocation[0], antLocation[1] + 1)
    elif (antDirection == 180): # DOWN
        antLocation = (antLocation[0]+1, antLocation[1])
    else: #(antDirection == 270 or antDirection == -90): #LEFT
        antLocation = (antLocation[0], antLocation[1] - 1)
        antDirection = 270
    mat.set_data(grid)
    return [mat]
    
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
mat = ax.matshow(grid)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a function that creates the individual frames (for each time point `t`). Then pass this function to `animation.FuncAnimation()`. Since you're working with global variables, `update()` doesn't need to return anything.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

antLocation = (15,15) # (y,x)
antDirection = 270
grid = [[0 for i in range(30)].copy() for _ in range(30)]

def update(data):
    global grid
    global antLocation
    global antDirection
    if(grid[antLocation[0]][antLocation[1]] == 0):
        antDirection +=90
        grid[antLocation[0]][antLocation[1]] = 1
    else:
        antDirection -=90
        grid[antLocation[0]][antLocation[1]] = 0
    if (antDirection == 0 or antDirection == 360): #UP
        antLocation = (antLocation[0]-1, antLocation[1])
        antDirection = 0
    elif (antDirection == 90): #RIGHT
        antLocation = (antLocation[0], antLocation[1] + 1)
    elif (antDirection == 180): # DOWN
        antLocation = (antLocation[0]+1, antLocation[1])
    else: #(antDirection == 270 or antDirection == -90): #LEFT
        antLocation = (antLocation[0], antLocation[1] - 1)
        antDirection = 270
    
def frame(t):
    """
    Update the grid and return a plot of the earlier grid.
    t (time) is not used, but necessary to be able to pass
    this function to matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.
    """
    plt.cla()
    image = plt.imshow(grid, cmap='Greys')
    update(grid)
    return image

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, frame)
plt.show()
```